# Impact of deprecated std::unary_function and std:: binary_function?

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::unary_function` and `std::binary_function` were depreacated in c++11. I have two doubts.

1. Does `std::unary_function` or `std::binary_function` come into play only if function is explicitly derived from them. like this:

```
struct derivedsmthing:  std::unary_function<smthing> ?
```

2. if not, i.e. some functions will get impacted even if it's not explicitly derived from these two? what are those functions?

Comment: Note: it was removed in C++17

Comment: yes they only have an effect where they're explicitly used